# Mock modules using jest that are imported using import * to test react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

File name Postman.js

```
"use strict";

define([], function() {
    var postManSingleton = (function() {
        var postManInstance
            , createPostMan = function() {
                var events = {}; 
                return  {
                    publish: function(event, payload) {
                        if(!events.hasOwnProperty(event)) 
                            return;
                        events[event].forEach(function(listener){
                            listener(payload || {});
                        });

                    },
                    subscribe: function(event, listener) {
                        if(!events.hasOwnProperty(event)) 
                            events[event] = [];

                        var index = events[event].push(listener)-1;
                        return {
                            remove: function () {
                                delete events[event][index];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            };

        return {
            getInstance: function() {
                if(!postManInstance)
                    postManInstance = createPostMan();
                return postManInstance;
            }
        } 
    }());  
    return postManSingleton.getInstance();
});
```

Importing this file as in index.test.js

```
import * as Postman from 'postman.js';
```

How do I mock its publish and subscribe events in jest.
I have tried

```
jest.mock('Postman.publish', () =>({//some code}))
```

Error : `Cannot find module Postman.publish from 'index.test.js'`

Please help how it is possible to  mock the above file. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Postman.js is in AMD & Jest does not support AMD. So you need to convert AMD to commonjs.

You can use [babel-plugin-transform-amd-to-commonjs](https://github.com/msrose/babel-plugin-transform-amd-to-commonjs) for conversion.